# jQuery 'error' class stays after cleaning up said 'error'

Tags: jquery

I've recently started dabbling in jquery and I've come up with this piece of code.
Basically whenever "submit" happens in "order_form" it checks if textfields are empty, if they're it adds the class "inputError" to whatever textfield is empty.
So far so good, now for this example I have 2 empty textfields, when I submit the "inputError" class gets added to both textfields, when I fill in my first textfield and submit it again it still shows the "inputError" on both textfields although I just filled one in.

jquery:

```
jQuery('form#order_form').submit(function() {
    jQuery('form#order_form .error').remove();
    var hasError = false;
    jQuery('.requiredFieldOrder').each(function() {
        if(jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).val()) == '') {             
            jQuery(this).addClass('inputError');
            hasError = true;
        }
    }); 
    if(!hasError) {         
        jQuery("#submittedOrder").css('display','none'); 
        jQuery(".loadingImg").css('display','block');

        var formInput = jQuery(this).serialize();
        jQuery.post(jQuery('#submitUrl').val(),formInput, function(data){
            jQuery('form#order_form').fadeOut('fast', function() {         
                jQuery(this).before('<p class="thanks"><strong>Thank you for your order!</p>');
            });
        });
    }   
    return false;   
});
```

css:

```
.inputError{border:2px solid red !important;}
```

Comment: You probably need to add a `removeClass('inputError')` somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only add (`addClass('inputError')`) the error class, but never actually remove it when there isn't an error. Add a `removeClass('inputError')` and it should work just fine:

```
...
if(jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).val()) == '') {             
    jQuery(this).addClass('inputError');
    hasError = true;
} else {   
    jQuery(this).removeClass('inputError');
}
...
```